# Background color in header and footer to be wider than the device width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, background-color

I'm trying to make the background color in header and footer to go beyond the device width and to be as wide as the width of a high resolution image on our website. I've created this jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/g8o9u1js/ ) which demonstrates our problem.

As you can see when you scroll horizontally to the right to see the rest of the image, the grey footer and header bars are cut off. Please note that we would like to keep the large high resolution image as it is (without reducing its dimensions) so that the user can scroll horizontally and see the detail in the image. Also we will have a number of high resolution images on different pages and these images will be of different widths so setting the width of a footer and header to a fixed width (e.g. 1920px) does not offer a universal solution.

Would you be so kind to offer a solution that would fix this problem? Many thanks for your help :)

Below is the code that we are using at the moment:

HTML

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="logodiv">
        <img id="logo" border="0" src="http://www.refugeeweek.org.uk/Resources/RefugeeWeek2012/Images/CounterpointsArts3.bmp">
        <br style="clear:both">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="description">     
    <h1 id="subject">Article with a high resolution image showing the top part of a nice painting </h1> 
    <p id="paragraph">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.</p> 
</div>

<div id="photo">    
    <img id="large" border="0" src="http://www.irmakennaway.com/images/stripe_27.jpg">   
</div> 

<div id="description">    
    <p id="paragraph">There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.</p>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <div id="footertext">
        <p id="details">About Us  |  Contact  |  Privacy<p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div#header {
width:100%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:10px;
background-color:#e1e1e1;
}

div#logodiv {
max-width:728px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width:744px) and (min-width:345px) {
div#logodiv {
max-width:93%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
}

img#logo {
max-width:100%;
height:auto;
float:left;
}

div#description {
max-width:728px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width:744px) and (min-width:345px) {
div#description {
max-width:93%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
}

div#photo {
width:100%;
overflow-x:scroll;
margin-top:2px;
margin-bottom:2px;   
}

img#large {
min-width:1600px;
margin:0px;
}

div#footer {
width:100%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
padding-top:4px;
padding-bottom:4px;
background-color:#e1e1e1;
}

div#footertext {
max-width:728px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width:744px) and (min-width:345px) {
div#footertext {
max-width:93%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
}

p#details {
max-width:728px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align:center;
}
```

**UPDATE**
The answer by the user Cdrini provides the best solution to our problem. The following 2 extra lines of code have provided a very neat and visually compelling effect. I have now updated the original fiddle to include this solution.

```
div#photo {
width:100%;
overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

Comment: Please check my updated answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can get what you want by modifying caeth's answer a bit. Add this to your CSS:

```
div#photo {
  width:100%;
  overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

Also be sure to include `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />` in the page's head to make `width:100%` be the device width on mobiles (this is not true by default).

(see the code here: http://jsbin.com/jovuhi/3/edit, or the result here: http://jsbin.com/jovuhi/3 )

Comment: You are a star! We weren't aware of the oveflow-x functionality so your neat solution (only 2 extra lines of code) has exceeded our expectations. The user can scroll to the right to see details in the image while other content remains visible. Brilliant! I've marked your answer with a green tick as the most helpful. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the image tags on the HTML and add this to your CSS styling:

**DEMO: [MY FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fjn70fsg/1/)**

CSS:

```
body, html{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#photo {
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url('http://www.irmakennaway.com/images/stripe_27.jpg');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="photo">    
       <!-- <img id="large" border="0" src="">   -->
 </div>
```

Comment: Also, you should look into [RESET CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). I use this for all my designs

Comment: Thank you CodeGodie for your fiddle. I should have been clearer in my question. I've now clarified my question by adding that "we would like to keep the large high resolution image as it is (without reducing its dimensions)."

Comment: This looks almost the way we want it apart from the fact that in your updated fiddle the high resolution image is cut off and the user cannot scroll to the right to see full width of a large image. Would you be so kind to see if it is possible to update your fiddle to include this feature. Please also note that we will have a number of high resolution images on different pages and these images will be of different widths and we are looking for a universal solution that would work on all of these pages.

Answer (score 0):

100% with is scaled on his container, wich is Body. Container of body = HTML.

SO:

```
html, body
{
margin: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#photo{
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: I've clarified my question by adding that "we would like to keep the large high resolution image as it is (without reducing its dimensions). Also we will have a number of high resolution images on different pages and these images will be of different widths so setting the width of a footer and header to a fixed width (e.g. 1920px) will not work."

Comment: @johnbell How about `body{ display: table}`? http://jsfiddle.net/caeth/g8o9u1js/42/

Comment: The problem with your solution is that now the user has to scroll to see the logo and the details in the footer. We would like the logo and the details in the footer to stay where they are. We would also like the logo and the footer to be responsive as in our jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the header to be as wide as the image you can just set it width with pixels

i'd rather let the image width be 100% so you don't need to scroll horizantali

Comment: Moneer, I should have been clearer in my question. I've now clarified my question by adding that "we would like to keep the large high resolution image as it is (without reducing its dimensions)."

Answer (score 0):

```
min-width: 728px;
width:100%;
```

use this code in header and footer

Comment: Hi Sia, many thanks for your help. I've tried your solutions in the jsfiddle but the grey bars were still cut off.

Answer (score -1):

Since you're using percentage widths on your website for each element, you will need your high-resolution image's width to be 100% width of the screen-size as well which you can set by using the following CSS:

```
img#large {
     width: 100%;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/g8o9u1js/17/).

If you'd like the width of the high-resolution image to remain unchanged then you will need to set a fixed width for your header and footer`<div>`'s like this:

```
#header {
     width: 1920px;
}

#footer {
     width: 1920px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g8o9u1js/19/)**.

**UPDATE:**

You will need to use a little jQuery over here and define the width of the image inside the `<img>`tag like `<img id="large" width="1920px" src="" />`. This is the jQuery code which you will need to use:

```
$('#header').width($('img#large').width());
$('#footer').width($('img#large').width());
```

What it does is that it assigns the width of the image to the `header` and the `footer` so that they are equal in width to the image. You can also test it using an image of another width and specifying its width inside the `<img>` tag like I've mentioned above.

Here's a working example:

```js
$('#header').width($('img#large').width());
$('#footer').width($('img#large').width());
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
div#header {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
div#logodiv {
  max-width: 728px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 744px) and (min-width: 345px) {
  div#logodiv {
    max-width: 93%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}
img#logo {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}
div#description {
  max-width: 728px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 744px) and (min-width: 345px) {
  div#description {
    max-width: 93%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}
div#footer {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
div#footertext {
  max-width: 728px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 744px) and (min-width: 345px) {
  div#footertext {
    max-width: 93%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}
p#details {
  max-width: 728px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <div id="logodiv">
    <img id="logo" border="0" src="http://www.refugeeweek.org.uk/Resources/RefugeeWeek2012/Images/CounterpointsArts3.bmp">
    <br style="clear:both">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="description">
  <h1 id="subject">Article with a high resolution image showing the top part of a nice painting </h1> 
  <p id="paragraph">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.</p>
</div>
<div id="photo">
  <img id="large" width="1920px" border="0" src="http://www.irmakennaway.com/images/stripe_27.jpg">
</div>
<div id="description">
  <p id="paragraph">There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.</p>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <div id="footertext">
    <p id="details">About Us | Contact | Privacy
      <p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g8o9u1js/34/)**.

Here's an **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/g8o9u1js/37/)** using an image whose width is `1648px` and you can see that the header and the footer has a width of `1648px` as well.

**UPDATE TWO:**

After thinking for quite some time, this is the only solution that I could come up with respect to all your requirements. I have modified your HTML structure a little bit by adding a `<span></span>` tag after the `header` div and the `footer` div and both those `<span>`'s have different classes. Moving forward, I have styled those span's using CSS and have assigned them a width equal to that of the high-resolution image using jQuery.

```js
$('.fullwidth').width($('img#large').width());
$('.fullwidthtwo').width($('img#large').width());
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
.fullwidth {
  background: rgb(225, 225, 225);
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 58px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.fullwidthtwo {
  background: rgb(225, 225, 225);
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 58px;
  margin-top: -58px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}
div#header {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  z-index: -1;
}
div#logodiv {
  max-width: 728px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 744px) and (min-width: 345px) {
  div#logodiv {
    max-width: 93%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}
img#logo {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}
div#description {
  max-width: 728px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 744px) and (min-width: 345px) {
  div#description {
    max-width: 93%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}
div#photo {
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
img#large {
  min-width: 1600px;
  margin: 0px;
}
div#footer {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
div#footertext {
  max-width: 728px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 744px) and (min-width: 345px) {
  div#footertext {
    max-width: 93%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}
p#details {
  max-width: 728px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <div id="logodiv">
    <img id="logo" border="0" src="http://www.refugeeweek.org.uk/Resources/RefugeeWeek2012/Images/CounterpointsArts3.bmp">
    <br style="clear:both">
  </div>
</div>
<span class="fullwidth"></span>

<div id="description">
  <h1 id="subject">Article with a high resolution image showing the top part of a nice painting </h1> 
  <p id="paragraph">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.</p>
</div>
<div id="photo">
  <img width="1920px" id="large" border="0" src="http://www.irmakennaway.com/images/stripe_27.jpg">
</div>
<div id="description">
  <p id="paragraph">There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.</p>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <div id="footertext">
    <p id="details">About Us | Contact | Privacy
      <p>
  </div>
</div> <span class="fullwidthtwo"></span>
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7e0r8na5/9/)**.

Comment: Would the genius behind the downvote care to explain what's wrong with my solution?

Comment: Fahad, thanks for your help. However, I should have been clearer in my question. I've now clarified my question by adding that "we would like to keep the large high resolution image as it is (without reducing its dimensions). Also we will have a number of high resolution images on different pages and these images will be of different widths so setting the width of a footer and header to a fixed width (e.g. 1920px) will not always work.

Comment: @johnbell Please check my updated answer above. This works perfectly as per your conditions.

Comment: Fahad, the problem with your solution is that now the user has to scroll to see the logo and the details in the footer. We would like the logo and the details in the footer to stay where they are. We would also like the logo and the footer to be responsive as in our jsfiddle.

Comment: @johnbell I've posted another solution above under `Update Two` above, please check. The logo and the details in the footer stay in the same place as they are in your example and they're responsive as wel.

Comment: Great work! Thank you:) Would it be also possible for the height of the grey header to be responsive? We would like the grey header to decrease its height as the width of the window/device is decreased. The decrease should be proportional to the decrease of the logo. You can see this in our original fiddle.

Comment: @johnbell I believe you can achieve that using `@media-queries` by setting a different height of `.fullwidth` at a width when the logo starts scaling negatively. Since you already have some `media-queries` inside your CSS, I think you will be able to understand what I am referring to. Please mark my answer as correct so that users can know your query has been answered. Thank you.

Comment: @Faham, many thanks for your hard work trying to help me. However cdrini's overflow-x:scroll answer above provides the best solution. Only two extra lines of code were required. I would vote you answer up if I had sufficient reputation :)